# Как в цикле map можно выполнить функцию?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Нужно сделать перебор в цикле используя 'map' и при этом вернуть результат выполнения 'map' используя при этом условие 'if'. Но уменя при попытке выполнить 
функцию ошибка.

Пример как я пытался сделать:

```js
let mass = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5
];

getValue(){
  return  mass.map((el) => (
      if(el <= 3){
        <div>el</div>
      }else{
        console.log(el, 'thi el')
      }
   ))
}
```

Как можно решить данную проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддерживаю ответ @Sapphiron по поводу использования `filter`.
Но если задача именно в map, то:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   mass: [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
 }
 render() {
  const getValue = this._getValue();
  return (
   <div>{getValue}</div>
  )
 }
 _getValue() {
  return this.state.mass.map(el => {
   if(el <= 3){
    return (
     <div>el</div>
    )
   } else {
    console.log(el, 'the el')
   }
  })
 }
 
}
ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Неправильный синтаксис map. Если внутри необходимы вычисления более 1 строки, их необходимо помещать в фигурные скобки и указывать `return`.

   `array.map(el => {
       return (<div>el</div>)
   })`
2. Если нужно исключить какие-то значения, необходимо использовать filter, а не `map`. Метод `map` возвращает массив того же размера, как и перебираемый, а если на какой-то итерации отсутствовал `return`, то вставит `undefined`.

Правильный вариант:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const arrElements = arr.filter((el, index) => {
  if(index < 3) {
    return <div>{el}</div>
  }
})
```

**Update.**

А если необходим просто срез массива, то лучше использовать `slice`, дабы не пробегать по всему массиву ради нескольких первых элементов.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const newArray = arr.slice(0, 3);
const arrElements = newArray.map(el => <div>{el}</div>);
```

Comment: судя по тому, что он проверяет значение элемента, а не индекс, slice ему не подойдет